# Can you please provide me the my sql query for below situation

Tags: mysql

```
    buildname   versionname   methodresult
    b1          v1            success
    b1          v2            failure
    b2          v1            success
    b2          v1            failure
    b1          v2            skip
    b2          v1            skip
    b3          v1            success        
    b3          v2            success
```

in above example i need to get only **buildname** **b3** which has only `success not filure or skip` using `mysql`.

**i need to get all buildnames which has success as method result .if one buildname has both success and failure i don't need that buildname even having success in any row.**

thank you

Comment: Why not use the typical SELECT statement with the WHERE condition to get what you want? Or are you new in SQL?

Comment: i need to get all buildnames which has success as method result .if one buildname has both success and failure i don't need that buildname even having success in any row.

Comment: OUTER JOIN the table to itself on the opposite criteria, but filter on only those rows whose outer joined result is NULL

Comment: can you provide me the query to above example

Comment: Good thing you edited your question. so basically you need to get the buildname with a result of no other than "success" regardless of the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
select * from table1 where buildname not in(
select distinct buildname from table1 where
methodresult in ('failure','skip'));
```

Thanks.

Here is the sql Fiddle.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccfd8/4)